# What does Solovay's theorem about the singular cardinal hypothesis above strongly compact cardinals say in level-by-level terms?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

[A theorem by Solovay](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486057/the-singular-cardinal-hypothesis-holds-above-a-compact-cardinal) says that if $\kappa$ is strongly compact then the singular cardinal hypothesis holds above $\kappa$. But if we only assume that $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-compact (edit: or $\lambda^+$-compact) for some singular $\lambda$, does it follow that the singular cardinal hypothesis holds at $\lambda$?

Edit: My motivation is that I wonder if the $\lambda$-supercompactness of $\kappa$, if $\lambda$ is a strong limit cardinal and $cof (\lambda) \lt \kappa$, implies that $\kappa$ is $2^{\lambda}$-supercompact, as I've read somewhere that $\lambda$-supercompact implies $\lambda^+$-supercompact if $cof (\lambda) \lt \kappa$.

Comment: Just looking at the outline of how the proof goes in Jech, it seems to clearly use the fact that $\kappa$ is $\lambda^+$- compact. (But if I recall correctly, that is sufficient.)

Comment: I've read somewhere that if $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact and $cof (\lambda) \lt \kappa$, it is $\lambda^+$'supercompact, I wouldn't be surprised is the same applies to strong compactness, and I'm primarily interested in the case for partial supercompactness, so that might be good enough.

Comment: If Im not mistaken, you probably do not need Solovays theorem for the application you have in mind. I think that if $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact and $\lambda$ is strong limit $>\kappa$ with $\mathrm{cof}(\lambda)<\kappa$ then the argument which shows $\kappa$ is $\lambda^+$-supercompact shows that infact $\kappa$ is $\lambda^{\mathrm{cof}(\lambda)}$-supercompact. As $\lambda$ is a strong limit, $2^\lambda=\lambda^{\mathrm{cof}(\lambda)}$.

Comment: @AndreasLietz I had seen the theorem in question cited as "if $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact and $cf(\lambda) \lt \kappa$ , then it is $\lambda^+$-supercompact" and _I dfidn't know the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The paper ["Strong axioms of infinity and elementary embeddings"](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(78)90031-1) by Solovay, Reinhardt and Kanamori proves this result for supercompact cardinals in the discussion after theorem 3.4 (it says that if $\kappa$ is supercompact, $\lambda$ is regular and $\lambda \ge \kappa$, then $\lambda = \lambda^{\lt \kappa}$, but if we set $\lambda = \mu^+$ such that $cf (\mu) \lt \kappa$, then we get $\mu^{\lt \kappa} = \mu^+$, that is the singular cardinal hypothesis at $\mu$), and it's clear that the proof only needs $\kappa$ to be $\mu^+$-supercompact.

The paper also proves (proposition 3.2) that if $\kappa$ is $\lambda$-supercompact, it is $\lambda^{\lt \kappa}$-supercompact. I looked up that paper because [a Mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414045/352898) cited it as source for the latter result.